# Missing framework ".NET 7.0", while I already have 8.0. I can't run a VSC app

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code

I am a beginner developer, that recently finished my studies and now just got employed. I am training about .NET, C# and ASP.NET Core, but I have faced a problem during my Microsoft courses (training there, with their learning paths). I am currently in the "Create a web UI with ASP.NET Core" module but when I cloned a project from github and was trying to run it, it always says that I must install .NET runtime 7.0 SDK, while I have 8.0. It said the same thing when I was going through "Create a web API with ASP.NET Core controllers" course, in the practice module, but I couldn't figure it out and just continued reading.

I just installed the 7.0 runtime, on my PC, but when I run the app in the VSC terminal, it still says that there is "this" framework missing.

I tried doing what Microsoft says at the download page:

> When your download completes, open a terminal and run the following commands to extract the SDK and make the commands available at the terminal:
>
> ```
> mkdir -p $HOME/dotnet && tar zxf dotnet-runtime-7.0.14-win-x64.exe -C $HOME/dotnet
> export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/dotnet
> export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet'
> ```

But terminal just does not accept them.

I also couldn't do the part where Microsoft says:

> The previous commands will only make the .NET SDK commands available for the terminal session in which it was run.
>
> You can edit your shell profile to permanently add the commands. There are several different shells available for Linux and each has a different profile. For example:
>
> Bash Shell: `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`
> Korn Shell: `~/.kshrc` or `.profile`
> Z Shell: `~/.zshrc` or `.zprofile`
> Edit the appropriate source file for your shell and add `:$HOME/dotnet` to the end of the existing `PATH` statement. If no `PATH` statement is included, add a new line with `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet`.
>
> Also add `export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/dotnet` to the end of the file.

on the download page.

Tried to find an explanation through youtube, but still couldn't figure it out.

I am getting confused and stressed out. Can anyone help?
I would appreciate it!

Comment: Are you trying these commands in the VSC terminal, as opposed to just your PC terminal?

Comment: @GSerg I used them, in both terminals. Firstly of course I tried PC Terminal, tried GitBash as well, after the first one didn#t even recognize them and lastly i tried thenVSC terminal. Same issue...

Comment: Why are you downloading dotnet-runtime-7.0.14-win-x64.exe to begin with if you are using Linux (are you even using Linux? I had that impression from your question but now I'm not sure)? And why are you installing the runtime when you need to install the SDK?

Comment: Windows, sorry,  there are so many .NET download files, that i confused it. In VSC the error states . "Framework: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '7.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: C:\Program Files\dotnet
The following frameworks were found:
  8.0.0 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Learn more:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=7.0.0&arch=x64&rid=win-x64&os=win10
dotnet watch ❌ Exited with error code -2147450730

Comment: So download the SDK for Windows x64 from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0, and follow the three steps with pictures on the resulting page. Ignore the terminal commands.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seems I was downloading the runtime instead of the sdk.